# React Native displaying nested array items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

The following code is for a single post, axios fetches the current post ID and stores the result in post array. Keep in mind, only ONE post is stored since this is fetching a single post. The ID and date display properly but if I try to display nested items like rendered content it doesn't work.

Here is what the API json result looks like:
[image]

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      post: []
    };
  }

getPost() {
    axios
      .get('single_post_api')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          post: response.data
        });
      });
}

componentDidMount() {    
    this.getPost();
  }

render() {
const data = this.state.post;

  return ( 
  <View>    
          <Text>{data.date}</Text>
          <Text>{data.slug}</Text>

///Neither of these work///
          <Text>{data.content.rendered}</Text>
          <Text>{data.content[0]}</Text>
////////////////////////////

  </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You cannot just [html](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) as a value in react.

Comment: @HMR I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: In the data `content.rendered` is html, you cannot do `<div>{content.rendered}</div>` but have to do it the way I mentioned earlier (because of xss attack). You could try `<pre>{JSON.sringify(data,undefined,2)}</pre>` and see where you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
render() {
  // If we run into a null, just render it as if we had an empty array.
  const posts = (this.state ?? this.state.posts) ? this.state.posts : [];

  return ( 
    <View>
      (posts.map((post, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <Text>{post.date}</Text>
          <Text>{post.slug}</Text>
          <Text>{post.content ? post.content.rendered : ""}</Text>
        </View>
      ));
  </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: const data = this.state.post; was a spelling mistake for this question, I have fixed it in the question. I added [response.data] but I still can't display the nested items.

Comment: Gotcha. I've modified my original answer.

Comment: This code works, just curious why I can't just put {post.content.rendered} , why do I need this before it: {post.content ? post.content.rendered : ""}

Comment: You could probably do {post.content.rendered} and be just fine. However, if post.content were ever null, it would throw an exception.

Comment: I get "Undefined is not an object" error if I do it that way, even though it's the exact same post and it displays properly with {post.content ? post.content.rendered : ""}

Comment: Since there are potentially multiple posts, perhaps post.content is null/undefined on one of them but not the rest?
Either way, I've just gotten in the habit of assuming that anything that can be null/undefined is just waiting to bite me when least expected.